# Best terminology to describe a time-series problem

Tags: time-series, survival, terminology

I have a problem that I would like to investigate regarding time-series data, but as I'm inexperienced in the field of statistics, I am unsure of the best terminology to describe my problem (so I can try to investigate further myself). *Any suggestions on approaches are of course welcome!*

**The problem can be summarised as:**

We receive several sets of deliveries on a periodic basis (although the timing can be imperfect and the periodicity varies between sets). For a particlar set of deliveries, sometimes a delivery has been missed.  Say the deliveries are typically quarterly, then ignoring the slight inaccuracy in delivery dates, then you would get something like this:

- **X** = delivered item
- **0** = expected delivery missed
- N = no expected delivery

  **X** N N **X** N N **0** N N **X** N N **0** N N **X** N N etc

I'm interested in how this can be analysed automatically, so given that one won't know the period in advance, I'd like to find a way to **a)** figure out the period, then **b)** see which expected deliveries are missing on that basis.

There is an added complication that in some cases deliveries are made on a cycle that isn't continuous, e.g. in a repeating three month period, they are delivered roughly on the first and second month and then not on the third.

Where I'm stumbling right away is that I don't know the formal terminology that one would use in describing this type of problem.  Is this best described a survival analysis problem with repeating events? Or just a discrete time-series problem?  Is there a special name for these sorts of binary event type time-series? (and also where the time measurements (i.e. the deliveries) do not occur at the same time - my understanding is that usually time-series data is gathered at the same interval.

Anyway, I'm keen to help myself if at all possible but if there are suggestions on the best approach (e.g. spectral analysis approaches?) I'd be grateful for those too.

Do ask for further clarification if I've missed something crucial or should give more detail.

Many thanks,
Neil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say it is categorical time series. By focussing one event ( N, X, or O) you could convert this as a binary time series.

My suggestions are:

1. You could start with simple Markov chain
2. Logistic regression with lag or seasonal dummies.

You could find some more stuff in this [link](http://www.utdallas.edu/~golden/ANNTALKS/Feb21talk/sld052.htm).